# Hiding a `DIV` element using a number value in jQuery

Tags: jquery, html

I am trying to hide a `DIV` named `#cart-total` when the value is less than $120. The `DIV` is hidden all the time. I also need to show an other `DIV` named `#minOrder` at the same time when the value is less than $120. The value will be set when the page is loaded or reloaded.

```
<script type="text/javascript">

$(document).ready(function() {
  var x = $("1,196.00").text();
  if (+x < 120)
    $("div#cart-total").hide();
});

</script>
```

Comment: `1,196.00` is not a valid selector!

Comment: `$("1,196.00")` <-- what is that??? O_O

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`var x = $("1,196.00")` is attempting to create a jQuery object from an HTML tag. Instead of

```
var x = $("1,196.00").text();
```

you should only need

```
var x = "1196.00";
```

Comment: 1,196.00 is a dollar value. How can I strip the comma out of that?

Comment: Well, you can do it yourself. Or you can use `x = x.replace(',','');` -- http://jsfiddle.net/mblase75/dDuPs/

Answer (score 0):

You first should convert your number in `int`.

I do not remember now exactly but one of these is the right one:

```
var intvalue = Math.floor( floatvalue );
var intvalue = Math.ceil( floatvalue ); 
var intvalue = Math.round( floatvalue );
```

then you will have easy life in your control.